# Bicycle is Having a hard time Shifting -- especially gears 13 and 14

Tags: gears, shifting

21 speed commuter bike. Raleigh 2011 brand.

After my gear shifter cable was broken, I took it into the shop to get it fixed. (4 days ago). Ever since, when shifting, it takes forever to actually shift and often does quite 'violently'. Shifting way past the trouble gears (past where I can currently handle) or way lower solves the problem. But that's not a good solution obviously.

Is there anything that I can do to fix this problem? What did they mess up at the bike store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cable needs adjusting.  A new cable will tend to stretch and go out of adjustment, so they should provide a free adjustment after replacing it.

Comment: Taking to the shop to make a post-service is the way to do, specially because you payed for it. Probably you could do it yourself, but that would not be fair :o)

Comment: Though adjusting shift cables is something that one should learn to do.  At the shop, ask the tech to let you watch, and ask him to explain what he's doing.